# react-native-camera crashed my application

Tags: react-native, qr-code, react-native-navigation, react-native-camera

When I add dependencies for QrCode Scanner(react-native-camera) and running project, my app is crashing and is not working.

[image]

Comment: Did you added permission key for Camera in info.Plist file ?

Answer (score 2):

**Add permissions to your app android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

**Insert the following lines in android/app/build.gradle:**

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
     missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'   

   }
 }
```

**for reference check this**
     [1]: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/blob/master/docs/installation.md#requirements

Answer (score 0):

I face the same situation when I ejected my app from expo and tries to use react-native-camera.

If you are using both **expo-camera** and **react-native-camera**, then the app will crash when the camera is open, just use one of the libraries will be fine, for me, I just uninstall both cameras, then re-install react-native-camera, and the camera works!